# Set height of actionbar for all platforms

Tags: android, html, css, android-actionbar

I have a custom action bar which I want to set its height to be compatible for all the platforms.

**Activity's theme**

```
<style name="MatchesTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyMatchesActionBar</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarTabStyle">@style/MyMatchesActionBarTabs</item>
    <item name="@android:attr/actionBarTabTextStyle">@style/MyMatchesActionBarTabsText</item>
 </style>

 <style name="MyMatchesActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">#FFEB00</item>
 </style>

 <style name="MyMatchesActionBarTabs">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/tab_matches_design</item>
    <item name="android:layout_gravity">fill_horizontal</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
 </style>

 <style name="MyMatchesActionBarTabsText" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:layout_gravity">fill_horizontal</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#01296e</item>
 </style>
```

Setting the height in `<item name="android:height">100pt</item>` for example will change its height but differs when I switch to another platform.

Is there any way to do that with weights or any other way?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

set dp instead:

```
<item name="android:height">100dp</item>
```

pt is point and if you set 100 pixel height to action bar it will appear according to the screen resolution of the device.

But setting a dp which is density pixel which translates this value into appropriate height for different devices.

Comment: was it that simple? lol thanks a lot. I now know the difference between dp and pt :) @vipulmittal